# Set format of mail forwarded from Gmail to SMS

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, iphone, sms

I have my Gmail set up with a filter to locate important messages and automatically forward them to [mynumber]@[phoneprovider].com with the result that I get an immediate SMS message on my iPhone.

That's great and works well, but...

The problem is that the message appears as a string of HTML on my phone. For example, all SMS messages from one source start out "body background-color: #333333; @font-face font-family" etc.

This is not only hard to read, but the SMS message is truncated before the text of the actual email appears.

So, is there a way to have Gmail automatically convert an email to plain text when received? Or force it to forward all emails in plain text? (I couldn't find a way to do the latter with filters or forwarding.)

I'm guessing by the time the message gets to my phone it's too late to do anything with it.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: nb: when I forward manually, I can select the content and choose "Remove Formatting". So I need a way to do that automatically.

Comment: Many services that send email notices give you an option to receive plaintext instead of HTML formatting. Can you get that source to do that?

Comment: Sadly, no, they only have a HTML option.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid, no, there's not a way to do that with just Gmail filters. There's no option to remove formatting or to just send the plain-text version.

(Normally I'd recommend my favorite interconnectivity tool, IFTTT, but I'm not sure that it will remove HTML formatting either. I'll need to do some testing.)